# Change Background img of div with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to change class of div with Fade In and out effect in loop, do anyone can help me with this please ?

I just want them to change automatically in fade in and out every 1s in loop.

my div

```css
.jumbotron {
 background-image: url('http://r6siegepro.pl/headerbgdark.png');
 background-color: #fff;
 background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.jumbotron2 {
 background-image: url('http://r6siegepro.pl/headerbgdark2.png');
 background-color: #fff;
 background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
h1 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
      <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
      <h1>SOME SAMPLE TEXT TO FILL EMPTY SPACE</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</p>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change class when you can just change the background image:

```
var swtich_bg = document.querySelectorAll('.jumbotron')[0];
var switch_bg_toggle; 

setInterval(function(){
  if ( switch_bg_toggle ) {
    swtich_bg.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://r6siegepro.pl/headerbgdark.png')";
    switch_bg_toggle = false;
  } else {
    swtich_bg.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://r6siegepro.pl/headerbgdark2.png')";
    switch_bg_toggle = true;
  }
}, 1000);
```

Just add transition in CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url('http://r6siegepro.pl/headerbgdark.png');
    background-color: #fff;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: background-image .5s linear;
}
```

Here you have JSBin: https://jsbin.com/mafimonoce/edit?html,output

Btw. don't set it for 1 second, use transition around 3 seconds and ~10 seconds interval.

Comment: Thank you, is exactly what i need it, Thank you so much again!

Comment: what about more variations if i want to add 3 or 4 images in a loop ?

Comment: Name images in order with a number a the end (some-image-1.jpg some-image-2.jpg etc.) and use this changed JS code https://jsbin.com/bonurovabo/edit?html,output

Comment: there is some white blink when script load new page, or sript fires sometimes, not sure why? is there anything i can do this, to prevent shows this white background even for a second ? i have changed images to jpg so they are like 80Kb not a 1 Mb any longer, I'm using transition: background-image 3s linear; and 10000 as time in js for changing the backgrounds.

Comment: In your original code you had `background-color: #fff;`, try changing it to some dark color, it might help to smooth the image loading.
If that does not help much you will need to preload the images you want to use further in the slideshow - how you might do that you can [learn more here](https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/).